# Thread sleep not waiting the correct amount

Tags: java, sleep

I am trying to use a multithread system where if I do not receive my answer in time I get a timeout and I get the following problem:

```java
public class proba6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        proba6 p = new proba6();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            p.cycle();
        }

    }

    public void cycle() {
        try {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            long endTime =System.nanoTime();
            long estimatedTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("estimatedTime > limit: " + estimatedTime + ">" + 1000000000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As a result, most of the time in the first cycle the `estimatedTime` is smaller than 1000000000. After that it works fine. Do you know the reason?

Comment: How much smaller is 'smaller'?

Comment: where is your threading code?

Comment: @pvpkiran There's no custom threading necessary for a `sleep`. It sleeps thread "main"

Comment: Where does it say that `Thread.sleep()` is exact? And there is no [tag:multithreading] here.

Comment: nanoTime came much later after currentMillis. So the sleep's ms might be still in the ms resolution aka precision - and not ns. But actually there is no guarantee by the specs. It is nice they err on the short side.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming that with *"smaller"* you mean "slightly smaller" like
`estimatedTime = 999999321` then this is normal.

Basically you stop your Thread, which means the OS needs to send an Interrupt, save the Thread's current state, call another thread to take its place and a second later, the system needs to wake your thread up again. So it will check if there is computing time available, if not it might try to interrupt another thread (see above) or maybe even wait a few microseconds for another thread to stop. Then it reinstates the state from your previously stopped thread and continues its execution.

Have a look at the <s>Docs</s> description for [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html), they say:

> (...) However, these sleep times are not guaranteed to be precise, because they are limited by the facilities provided by the underlying OS. Also, the sleep period can be terminated by interrupts, as we'll see in a later section. In any case, **you cannot assume that invoking sleep will suspend the thread for precisely the time period specified**.

Comment: I am sorry if this is not very precise or correct. But the topic is rather large and complicated.

Comment: 'Send an interrupt'?